# Jenkins ssh keys available to authenticated users

Tags: github, jenkins

I might be doing something wrong, but this seems to be the case for every jenkins install I've seen. By creating a new jenkins job, and adding a shell script task, I can

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

And of course see the key in the output log.

I use private github repos to host code for builds, so I do need some way to authenticate. The key also is permitted to commit, as we release from jenkins too.

Is there a way to mitigate jenkins users ability to view my keys without upsetting or restricting developers too much?

Comment: Why do you need to cat a *private* ssh key in a Jenkins job?

Comment: Have you read the question? Where does it say I NEED to? Apols for caps.

Comment: Right, so you mean: how do I prevent anyone to define a job that would expose the private key?

Comment: Yes, for example it would be useful if jenkins could confine users to the workspace directory of a job.

Comment: But if the private resource isn't managed by the account, that would make that job unable to access it, wouldn't it? That is in line with what I propose below, speaking of storing a private resource (here a token) in a non-conventional path (it can be also protected with another user or group, to prevent access by the user executing the Jenkins jobs on the agent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to mitigate the risk is by:

- not using ssh keys
- use rather a [dedicated token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-an-access-token-for-command-line-use) (that is easier to revoke)
- store that token in a non-conventional path that is only know from the scripts needing to authenticate, not from any Jenkins jobs.

Comment: I might suggest to the team here to use password based authentication for the github account Jenkins use so we can rid ourselves of the exposed key pair. On a whole, I think your suggestions are excellent.

Comment: Would a combo of jenkins, the envinject plugin and tokens make sense?

Comment: @Jepper it could make sense, it this isn't too complex to put in place.

Answer (score 0):

I worked out how to do it: Use manage-ssh-credentials + ssh-agent plugin.  Encrypt the private key, and paste in in the the manage ssh credentials UI. It is now available to all jobs. If you need to execute shell scripts using ssh, the required key can be loaded from the ssh-agent plugin inside a job.